# Variation of a tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, vector-fields

Let a change of coordinates be given by $x^{\mu}\to x^{\mu '}=x^{\mu}+\varepsilon \xi^{\mu}(x)$ with epsilon a small quantity.

Given a tensor $T$ we define $\delta T:=T'(x)-T(x)$. I guess this means $\delta T^{\mu}=T^{\mu '}(x)-T^{\mu}(x)$. I need to show that for a vector $V$

$\delta V^{\mu}=-\varepsilon[\xi^{\alpha}(\partial_a V^{\mu})-(\partial_{\alpha} \xi^{\mu})V^{\alpha}]+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)$.

Here's what I tried:

$\delta V^{\mu}=V^{\mu '}(x)-V^{\mu}(x)=V_x(dx^{\mu '})-V_x (dx^{\mu})=V(dx^{\mu '}-dx^{\mu})$.

Now since $x^{\mu '}-x^{\mu}=\varepsilon \xi^{\mu}$ we can get that:

$dx^{\mu '}-dx^{\mu}=\varepsilon d\xi^{\mu}=\varepsilon \xi_{\alpha}dx^{\alpha}$.

Finally:
$\delta V^{\mu}=\varepsilon V(\xi_{\alpha} dx^{\alpha})=\varepsilon (\xi_{\alpha}V^{\alpha})$

This looks pretty bad to me, any ideas on how to improve it?

Comment: This sounds more like a pure mathematics question.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment in the accepted answer above. We really have
$$
V'_\mu(x') dx'^\mu = V_\mu(x) dx^\mu \implies V'^\nu(x+\epsilon \xi) (  \delta^\mu_\nu + \epsilon \partial_\nu \xi^\mu ) dx^\mu = V_\mu(x) dx^\mu
$$
Then
$$
V'^\mu  + \epsilon \xi^\nu \partial_\nu V^\mu + \epsilon V^\nu \partial_\nu \xi^\mu = V^\mu + O(\epsilon^2)
$$
Every field above is evaluated at the point $x$. Then, by definition
$$
\delta V^\mu = V'^\mu - V^\mu = - \epsilon (  \xi^\nu \partial_\nu V^\mu +  V^\nu \partial_\nu \xi^\mu )  + O(\epsilon^2)
$$